# Best use of HttpClient in PowerShell Binary Module

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm upgrading some scripts that use powershell commands like Invoke-WebRequest and Convert-FromJson to a binary module using HttpClient and System.Text.Json

All is well I have a much faster module and a shared Library I can use in other .net projects.

My data access service depends on an HttpClient, in the command this is instantiated in the beginProccess method of the command/class.  This will at least re-use the client for multiple pipeline inputs.

My question is, can the client be further reused?  Would I then risk multithread issues?  Can it belong to the module and even better could the module own a HttpClientFactory?

Comment: Going to study this when I get a chance. 
Looks like ms instantiate using a factory method called new.  I'm not familiar with this not a constructor by the look, why called new?
 https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebRequestPSCmdlet.Common.cs#L1052

Comment: new() is a c# 9 feature. Syntactic sugar for new Object()

Answer (score 0):

I thought a good answer to this would be an analysis of the [Invoke-WebRequest source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebRequestPSCmdlet.Common.cs).

This abstract class inherits `PSCmdlet` which is a prerequisite for a PowerShell Cmdlet.  It has a factory method that instantiates and returns an `HttpClient` called `GetHttpClient` with the desired configuration.

This method is used in the `GetResponse` method to create a new client in case of error but typically uses an `HttpClient` given as a parameter.  In the case of error, the new client is disposed of immediately after it fetches an `HttpRequestMessage` via the `using` syntax.

`ProcessRecord` also creates and disposes of a client for use with the `GetResponse` method.

This case study suggests that in a PowerShell Cmdlet, an `HttpClient` should be very short lived and not be shared between invocations of the Cmdlet or even for different pipeline input of the Cmdlet.

Comment: asked for comment on GitHub https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/discussions/16755